# SSIS Dynamic connection string not working, throwing a OLEDB error

Tags: ssis, expression

I am trying to setup dynamic connection string using the Expression-->ConnectionString:

```
(DT_WSTR, 200)"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
+  @[User::file_path]  
+ (DT_WSTR, 200)";Extended Properties=" 
+ (DT_WSTR, 200) "\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES\";"
```

The evaluation result: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Download\Root\;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";`

It matches with the manual ConnectionString but still not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your evaluation result doesn't contain a file name, just a path.

Comment: Hi,
I cannot mark this answer as I do not have enough reputation to do so. I think you are right. Basically I was looking at the manual connection string value and tried to match that using my expression. Now I have realised if I want to expression I have to identify the file name exclusively.

Many thanks.